# Is it a good idea to run `...par.map(` on large lists directly?

Tags: scala, parallel-collections

Let's say I have a somewhat large (several millions of items, or so) list of strings. Is it a good idea to run something like this:

```
val updatedList = myList.par.map(someAction).toList
```

Or would it be a better idea to group the list before running `...par.map(`, like this:

```
val numberOfCores = Runtime.getRuntime.availableProcessors
val updatedList = 
  myList.grouped(numberOfCores).toList.par.map(_.map(someAction)).toList.flatten
```

UPDATE:
Given that `someAction` is quite expensive (comparing to `grouped`, `toList`, etc.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Run `par.map` directly, as it already takes the number of cores into account. However, do not keep a `List`, as that requires a full copy to make into a parallel collection. Instead, use `Vector`.

Answer (score 8):

As suggested, avoid using lists and `par`, since that entails copying the list into a collection that can be easily traversed in parallel. See the [Parallel Collections Overview](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/parallel-collections/conversions.html) for an explanation.

As described in the [section on concrete parallel collection classes](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/parallel-collections/concrete-parallel-collections.html), a `ParVector` may be less efficient for the `map` operation than a `ParArray`, so if you're really concerned about performance, it may make sense to use a parallel array.

But, if `someAction` is expensive enough, then its computational cost will hide the sequential bottlenecks in `toList` and `par`.